# AVL tree implementation via inheritance

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I was asked to implement an AVL tree , and I did it- now it works for all stress-tests I could think about. now I see we were advised to implement it, s.t it inherits from binary search tree that inherits from a binary tree. I want to it right- I'll be glad to get an advice on which invariants (fields that have to appear) should appear in each of them ( the binary tree, the search and the AVL). 
thank you!
here is my implementation for it:
[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text.

Comment: this will easily cause stack overflow if the depth of the tree is big in the destructor.

Comment: also, in C++, inheritance is usually never the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you some tips. When coding object oriented code, I find it useful to design top down - that is, implement the parent class, and then inherit and decide what needs to be added/overriden.

Examples:

**binary tree:**

1. Well, you obviously need a node, with two children (how you implement that is your thing). Node needs a data field.
2. Insertion - with no restriction, you can insert after a node to the left, to the right or replace the parent. Which of these you implement and how is up to you.
3. Traversal - go left than right, right than left etc...
4. Lookup has no restriction, so you will have to traverse the entire tree (worst case)

All these are general properties of a binary tree. You could come up with more (printing for debug uses etc...). We inherit all these and start with:

**binary search tree**

1. Node doesn't really change, does it?
2. Well now insertion is not determined at all by you! You do not insert to a specific node you insert to the entire tree. You need to look for the place you want to insert, then you can call the **base insertion**.
3. Traversal doesn't change does it?
4. Lookup can be improved drastically, and probably should be overridden completely.
5. You can think of new methods that didn't make sense for a non ordered search tree, though I don't have any coming to mind. Some may consider adding a **compare** (less than for example) operator to a node, overloading it to compare to the data type or another node.

Finally, you inherit this to make an **AVL** tree. Try and consider what can be inherited as is, what needs to be completely overridden, and what needs some work before calling a base class. You can google/wikipedia for common tree operations (namely I didn't mention delete, for example). Good luck.

**EDIT**

AS davmac mentions, the node of an AVL changes - it needs an additional field! We had two children we inherited, and the data field, but now we also need a balance factor. This is an example of when to add a field.

Comment: Good overview. One complication here is that AVL trees need to store additional data in the nodes - so `AVLTree<T>` might need to extend `BinarySearchTree<AVLNode<T>>` rather than `BinarySearchTree<T>`.

Comment: Correct! I didn't want to give hints for AVL itself, but I guess this one warrants attention. Also added a possible comparison method for the ordered tree.

Comment: @davmac this is exactly what i confronted right now ! how to make avlTree to extend BinarySearchTree<AVLnode>?

Comment: Those are conceptually the same. An `AVLnode` determines the tree itself, just adds a field and implements stuff like insertion.